# How to Set sub module access permission for all type of user in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My user access permission check box is not working for admin, authenticated,anonymous 
    user.I have created submodule and used hook_permission also it show check box on admin
    but not working on checked and unchecked.Please give me solution?
    Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably got voted down because you have no code examples. It does make it difficult to answer your question, but it's pretty simple so I'll give it a shot.

If you are seeing the checkbox on the permissions page, then I know your hook_permission() is most likely properly declared.

You did not mention how you are checking permission, so I will go through 2 methods:

1) If you are using hook_menu(), look at the `access_arguments` line. That is how you would set permissions for an entire page.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['abc/def'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    'access arguments' => array('administer my module')
  );
  return $items;
}
```

2) If you are wanting to check permission in a section of code, as a condition, you would use it this way.

```
if (user_access('administer my module')) {
  // show administrator stuff here
}
```

Comment: I have used first method it show check box on admin but not working.How it will use to restrict the user to access the following module developed by developer??